# Same dimensions but different results responsive CSS

Tags: css

I'm having problems with the CSS of this page I'm creating. The page is perfoming differently on the mobile than it is on the desktop version even in **the same screen sizes**! See the following print of Firefox Inspector:
[image]

**Both pages has the same screen sizes** of 412x883 pixels, **but** while **the first example simulates the Galaxy Note 20 Ultra Linux and breaks** the page (for example the menu text has 16px and looks tiny on the phone), **the second only simulates it's screen size and works** just fine (same 16px but readable). And this don't happen in all mobiles versions, the iPad and Kindle versions work just fine. Seens to be a phone problem and I have no idea why. **Can it be because I'm working with 100vh heights on the header and other blocks?** Any CSS expert that can help me?

I'm not posting the page code here with snippet cause it has a big SVG so more caracters than allowed by Stackoverflow,I've posted it on JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lucasmarinifalbo/ejq5fanv/1/ `.`

Update: It don't seen to be a DPR problem. For instance, two mobile versions with the same screen width and same DPR (but different) heights displays the page differently:
[image]

Comment: The answer is in the screenshot, dpr is 3.5 / 1

Comment: But if I use the responsive state instead of the phone emulator of the firefox inspector with the same 3.5 DPR, the page will look normal. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

My HTML didn't had the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`, so the DPR was messing around the screen sizes :X

Embarrassing hahaha, but I won't delete the question because can help someone.